Rmarkdown table
I am creating an analysis in Rmarkdown that has to be in Arial font throughout and there is a table that has a mixture of Arial and Computer Modern fonts.
Below is a sample code for this chunk and a picture of the table with the mixture of fonts.
````r tbl01, results='asis', echo=F, warning=F, message=F, include=TRUE, cache=F}

library(modelsummary)

mod <- list(
    lm(mpg ~ qsec + drat, mtcars),
    lm(hp ~ qsec + drat, mtcars)  )

fun <- function(model) data.frame("DV" = insight::find_response(model))

modelsummary(mod, gof_function = fun)
````



Off-topic: Why do you think, increasing visual noise from mixing fonts and alignments conveys your message more easily to your readers? Honestly, I suggest to rethink your typographical approach beyond „how do I xyz?“ .

@MS-SPO did you read the question?

@cfr, yes. That's why my comment starts with "Off-topic".

@MS-SPO but the OP is trying to get rid of the very thing you're criticising. the question is, 'how can I get rid of this weird mixture of fonts?' and you're saying, 'you should really rethink that weird mixture of fonts'.

@cfr, thank you. I still don’t read the wish …

@MS-SPO hmm. maybe I'm just missing something, then. how do you read '[my document] has to be in Arial font throughout and there is a table that has a mixture of Arial and Computer Modern fonts'. as I read that, the OP needs arial but there's this table which has cm as well and that's the problem.

May be the text is premature …

Well, except that the marks of the R cell are wrong, your R code "as is" works fine for me in  a default empty document, so I guess it will be enough for you to not do whatever you are doing to cause this issue, maybe in with you custom template, or in your preamble, or in your YAML header. Try the MWE below, if this document does not work out fine for you, then you should consider other types of causes.

---
output:
  pdf_document: default
---

``` {r tbl01, results='asis', echo=F, warning=F, message=F, include=TRUE, cache=F}

library(modelsummary)


mod <- list(
    lm(mpg ~ qsec + drat, mtcars),
    lm(hp ~ qsec + drat, mtcars)  )

fun <- function(model) data.frame("DV" = insight::find_response(model))

modelsummary(mod, gof_function = fun)

```
The end.

If you want all the document with sans serif font (sorry, I cannot test with the Arial font) including some like this in the header reproduce the issue:
header-includes:
- \renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} 

Now  the sans serif font is only in the first column, but note that if you change the output of the summary:
    modelsummary(mod, gof_function = fun, output="markdown")

This will force the output to be plain text, without any font format, and therefore the result will be:

